What is this usage of 周り?

A character is talking on the phone. These two dialogs are in sequence. As far I can understand the context, because he's sick he intends to close his shop. So he's communicating to the person on the phone the current situation. 　The character runs a bar.
I can't quite make sense of 店周り here. I can tell he's talking about office work procedure but?

I think 店周り means things related to shop. Probably the same 周り used in a word 水回り.
